# What does 'Imperial' mean with regards to beer style?

Tags: beer-styles, imperial

I've seen the adjective "Imperial" tacked on at the beginning of a number of beer styles recently: Imperial Stout, Imperial Brown Ale, Imperial Red Ale, etc.

What does it mean exactly, is it just higher alcohol content or something like that?

Comment: Delicious! Just popped my first GLBCo. Lake Erie Monster. It's an Imperial India Pale Ale. Wanna taste "imperial"? Try one. Silky smooth for a double with a Czarist finish destined to inspire a revolution. 9.1 ABV with just the right punch at 80 IBU. Maybe 1 more I'm not driving.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

English brewers, brewing beer for the Russian Czar's court brewed a beer with a high ABV to try and impress the royalty of Russia.  Lots of hops were added to balance the malt, and survive the journey to Russia.  This was the original Russian Imperial Stout.

As will all things, American Craft breweries have now taken this name to put a spin on any beer that is higher alcohol than its traditional counterpart.  It may also contain a lot more hops than normal.

Examples, Imperial IPA, Imperial Pilsner, Imperial Brown ale... you get the idea.

Comment: There are others synonyms, but "Double" is a term frequently used in the place of Imperial.

Comment: @Luciano the BJCP in 2008 listed Imperial as more prominent, but in 2015 lists Double as more prominent.

Answer (score 9):

It is part marketing and part tradition.

The term has origins in high gravity and hopped porters exported from England.  The *BJCP 2008 Style Guidelines* has this to say about the [Russian Imperial Stout](http://www.bjcp.org/2008styles/style13.php#1f):

> Brewed to high gravity and hopping
>   level in England for export to the
>   Baltic States and Russia. Said to be
>   popular with the Russian Imperial
>   Court. Today is even more popular with
>   American craft brewers, who have
>   extended the style with unique
>   American characteristics.

"Imperial" is this brewing world's "EXTREME!"  Higher alcohol, more hops, more malt, more everything!  Quoth the BJCP about [Imperial IPA](http://www.bjcp.org/2008styles/style14.php#1c):

> A recent American innovation
>   reflecting the trend of American craft
>   brewers “pushing the envelope” to
>   satisfy the need of hop aficionados
>   for increasingly intense products. The
>   adjective “Imperial” is arbitrary and
>   simply implies a stronger version of
>   an IPA; “double,” “extra,” “extreme,”
>   or any other variety of adjectives
>   would be equally valid.

Comment: more from BJCP 2015 Style Guidelines: "The adjective “double" is arbitrary and simply
implies a stronger version of an IPA; “imperial,” “extra,”
“extreme,” or any other variety of adjectives would be equally
valid, although the modern American market seems to have
now coalesced around the “double” term."

Comment: the BJCP seems to believe that Double has become the more predominant term, these days.

Comment: (I doubt the term Double will ever override the Imperial in Imperial Stout, though)

Answer (score 2):

I always consider Imperial to mean "bigger" (higher abv). A more extreme version of the style with more of various ingredients. There are larger additions of specific ingredients generally based on the style, such as an Imperial IPA probably is more heavily hopped. It also seems that the word "double" could easily be interchanged most of the time.

im·pe·ri·al  (m-pîr-l)
adj.
1. Of, relating to, or suggestive of an empire or a sovereign, especially an emperor or empress: imperial rule; the imperial palace.
2. Ruling over extensive territories or over colonies or dependencies: imperial nations.
3.
a. Having supreme authority; sovereign.
b. Regal; majestic.
4. Outstanding in size or quality.

Outstanding in size or quality seems to apply to beer quite nicely.

Comment: Majestic.     .

Answer (score 1):

Surface meaning when picking up a bottle at the store: more. More hops, more malt - more ABV.

Additionally, it also refers to *some* of the beer's history. Imperial Indian Pale Ale relates to the exporting of beer from England to India during their imperial reign (fact check?).
Similarly, [Imperial Stouts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stout#Imperial%5Fstout) were exported from England to Catherine II of Russia.

Comment: Imperial IPA is nothing to do with the British Empire.  Imperial (India) Pale Ale is an North American name for either a IPA or in the case of IIPA a stronger IPA, much like an Imperial Stout is a stronger, more intense stout.

Answer (score 0):

I believe a beer must be at least 8.5% alc or 9% to be an Imperial beer. For example an IPA with 8% alc is not imperial, and Imperial IPA would be I believe at least 8.5-9% and up.

Comment: Must? Who makes these rules?

Comment: the BJCP makes guidelines, but there are no real rules. If a beer deviates from the guidelines too much, it will likely score lower if being officially judged... (imagine a light-colored porter or an ipa without any hops) ...If we ignore the judging aspect, it can also make a consumer disappointed if their expectations are not met.